# How do I name a function that takes an object `A` and a set `{A, B}` as arguments, then returns `B`?

Tags: python, function, naming-conventions, naming

What is a good name for the following function (as implemented in Python)?

```
def a_function(element, a_set):
    if a_set[0] == element:
        return a_set[1]
    if a_set[1] == element:
        return a_set[0]

assert 'A' == a_function('B', ['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: My `super_magical_awesome_comparison_and_validator_function(element, a_set)`. Just kidding. Just do something like `get_not` or something

Comment: How about `a_set[not a_set.index(element)]` :D

Comment: @hllau you have the minor problem that Python has a `set`, but that isn't what you're using... I would rename the argument, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: you are welcome to correct them, although this is not the focus of the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: or I will have to say `a list of 2 elements` which is pretty long.

Comment: @hilau `pair` is fairly neutral and easily denotes that, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a different function name, different argument names and a docstring to make it clear what's going on, something like:

```
def get_other(current, both):
    """Return the element from 'both' that is not 'current'."""
    ...
```

Note that `both` implies a pair without anything long-winded, and doesn't specify the `type` required.

You can use your own implementation or Joel's; as long as the function does what it says, it doesn't really matter how it's implemented (barring performance concerns, edge cases, etc.).

However, to work with non-indexable containers (like the `set`, or the keys of a `dict`) without having to explicitly test what `both` is, I would probably go for:

```
def get_other(current, both):
    """Return the element from 'both' that is not 'current'."""
    for item in both:
        if item != current:
            return item
```

Indeed, if `len(both) > 2`, this will just return the first item in it that isn't equal to `current` - you can add checks for this if this is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: This complies with many best practises of Python.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what jonrsharpe proposes (which I like, don't get me wrong), here is a one-line version that uses sets as mentioned in the question title:

```
>>> def get_other(element, pair):
...   """Get the other element from a pair"""
...   return (set(pair) - set([element])).pop()
...
```

This computes the set difference of `element` and `pair` then `pop`s a random member from the resulting set (which should ideally be of size 1).

Here's a few examples of it working over different iterable data types:

```
>>> get_other('B', {'A', 'B'})
'A'
>>> get_other('B', ['A', 'B'])
'A'
>>> get_other('A', ['A', 'B'])
'B'
>>> get_other('B', {'A': 1, 'B': 2})
'A'
>>> get_other('B', 'AB')
'A'
>>> get_other(5, {1, 5})
1
```

If `len(pair) > 2` or `element not in pair`, the element you get back is undefined, but will always be an element from `pair`:

```
>>> get_other('B', 'ABC')
'C'
>>> get_other('B', 'ABCDEF')
'E'
```

Finally, if `pair` is empty or `pair == {element}`, it will raise a `KeyError`:

```
>>> get_other('B', 'B')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_other
KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'
```